# Error executing laravel new myproject - failed to open stream ( routes/api.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm installing a fresh Laravel 5.7 with this command:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel new plugin-test3
```

here is the full log:

```
Crafting application...
You should verify that the "storage" and "bootstrap/cache" directories are writable.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 86 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.5.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v4.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v4.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/routing (v4.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/process (v4.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/contracts (v1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug (v4.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v4.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v4.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v4.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.99): Loading from cache
  - Installing ramsey/uuid (3.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing opis/closure (3.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/translation (v4.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.36.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.24.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.49): Loading from cache
  - Installing erusev/parsedown (1.7.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (2.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.5.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/slack-notification-channel (v1.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/framework (v5.7.19): Loading from cache
  - Installing lcobucci/jwt (3.2.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/promise (v1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/httplug (v1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/guzzle6-adapter (v1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing zendframework/zend-diactoros (1.8.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing nexmo/client (1.6.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/nexmo-notification-channel (v1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing fideloper/proxy (4.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (v0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.9.9): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/tinker (v1.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing beyondcode/laravel-dump-server (1.2.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing mockery/mockery (1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing filp/whoops (2.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing nunomaduro/collision (v2.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/version (2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/resource-operations (2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/object-reflector (1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (3.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/object-enumerator (3.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/global-state (2.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/exporter (3.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/environment (4.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/diff (3.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/comparator (3.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (2.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (2.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (3.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (6.1.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing webmozart/assert (1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (0.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (4.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phar-io/version (2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phar-io/manifest (1.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.8.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (7.5.1): Loading from cache
symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection (For loading routes from a service)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml (For using the YAML loader)
symfony/contracts suggests installing psr/cache (When using the Cache contracts)
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/cache-contracts-implementation
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/service-contracts-implementation
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/lock
swiftmailer/swiftmailer suggests installing true/punycode (Needed to support internationalized email addresses, if ext-intl is not installed)
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ircmaxell/random-lib (Provides RandomLib for use with the RandomLibAdapter)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides the PECL libsodium extension for use with the SodiumRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-uuid (Provides the PECL UUID extension for use with the PeclUuidTimeGenerator and PeclUuidRandomGenerator)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing moontoast/math (Provides support for converting UUID to 128-bit integer (in string form).)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-doctrine (Allows the use of Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid as Doctrine field type.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-console (A console application for generating UUIDs with ramsey/uuid)
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/yaml
nesbot/carbon suggests installing friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer (Needed for the `composer phpcs` command. Allow to automatically fix code style.)
nesbot/carbon suggests installing phpstan/phpstan (Needed for the `composer phpstan` command. Allow to detect potential errors.)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server via PHP Driver)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing sentry/sentry (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v3)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter decorator for metadata caching)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use EventableFilesystem)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to use ZipArchive adapter)
league/flysystem suggests installing spatie/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 (Allows you to use Dropbox storage for PHP 5 applications)
laravel/framework suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Required to use the SQS queue driver and SES mail driver (^3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Required to rename columns and drop SQLite columns (^2.6).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Required to use the Flysystem S3 driver (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Required to use the Flysystem cache (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Required to use the Flysystem Rackspace driver (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Required to use the Flysystem SFTP driver (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing moontoast/math (Required to use ordered UUIDs (^1.1).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk queue driver (^3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing predis/predis (Required to use the redis cache and queue drivers (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use the Pusher broadcast driver (^3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/dom-crawler (Required to use most of the crawler integration testing tools (^4.1).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (Required to psr7 bridging features (^1.0).)
lcobucci/jwt suggests installing mdanter/ecc (Required to use Elliptic Curves based algorithms.)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation. You'll want this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit.)
filp/whoops suggests installing whoops/soap (Formats errors as SOAP responses)
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (^2.6.0)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (^2.0)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> @php artisan key:generate --ansi
PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: require(/Users/julien/Documents/Projets/plugin-test3/routes/api.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/julien/Documents/Projets/plugin-test3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:417
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/julien/Documents/Projets/plugin-test3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(417): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'require(/Users/...', '/Users/julien/D...', 417, Array)
#1 /Users/julien/Documents/Projets/plugin-test3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(417): require()
#2 /Users/julien/Documents/Projets/plugin-test3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(373): Illuminate\Routing\Router->loadRoutes('/Users/julien/D...')
#3 /Users/julien/Documents/Projets/plugin-test3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteRegistrar.php(121): Illuminate\Routing\Router->group(Array, '/Users/julien/D...')
#4 /Users/julien/Documents/Projets/plugin-t in /Users/julien/Documents/Projets/plugin-test3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php on line 417
PHP Fatal error:  Illuminate\Routing\Router::loadRoutes(): Failed opening required '/Users/julien/Documents/Projets/plugin-test3/routes/api.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.8/share/php/pear') in /Users/julien/Documents/Projets/plugin-test3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php on line 417

In Router.php line 417:

  Illuminate\Routing\Router::loadRoutes(): Failed opening required '/Users/ju  
  lien/Documents/Projets/plugin-test3/routes/api.php' (include_path='.:/usr/l  
  ocal/Cellar/php/7.2.8/share/php/pear')                                       


Script @php artisan key:generate --ansi handling the post-create-project-cmd event returned with error code 255
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

I have the latest version of laravel installer:

```
 ~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel --version       
--> Laravel Installer 2.0.1
```

I also have php7.2

```
$ php --version                                                                                            
PHP 7.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul 19 2018 12:15:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.8, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

What can I do about that?

Comment: Your folder have permission where you have installed larave?

Comment: Yes, I guess, all files are written. I checked for /Users/julien/Documents/Projets/plugin-test3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php and file exists

Comment: but does `plugin-test3/routes/api.php` exist and do you have read permission?

Comment: I didn't change nothing, and now, it is working...